# comparing and replacing the elements of a nested list

Tags: python

I have got a list which is:

```
mylist = {
           'a': [(-1,-1), (0.2,0.4)] 
           'b': [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1)]
           'c': [(-1,-1), (-1,-1)]
           'd': [(0.15,0.35), (0.05,0.15)]
          }
```

I have to get an output which will be like the following:

```
 mylist = {
           'a': [(0.3, 0.35), (0.2,0.4)] 
           'b': [(0.3,0.35), (0.05,0.15)]
           'c': [(0.15,0.35), (0.05,0.15)]
           'd': [(0.15,0.35), (0.05,0.15)]
          }
```

The list above looks like this when I print it,

```
mylist = [ ('a', [ (-1, -1), (0.2, 0.4) ] ), 
           ('b', [ (0.3, 1.0), (-1, -1) ] ), 
           ('c', [ (-1, -1), (-1, -1) ] ), 
           ('d', [ (0.15, 0.35), (0.05, 0.15) ] ) ]
```

Now the algorithm is like the following:

```
1st iteration: Compare a[0] and b[0] ie (-1, -1) and (0.3, 1.0). 
               Here replace (-1, -1) by (0.3, 1.0). 
               Rule: (-1, -1) is considered as empty or not in use so 
                     it gets replaced while comparison. 

               Similarly, compare a[1] and b[1] ie (0.2, 0.4) and (-1, -1). 
               Here keep the same value as b[1] is empty so no change. 

               Hence the new elements of 'a' are (0.3, 1.0), (0.2, 0.4). 
               Rule: if comparing with empty one then keep the same values.

2nd iteration: Compare new values of a[0] and c[0] ie (0.3, 1.0) and (-1, -1). 
               Here again no change. 
               Similarly, compare new values of a[1] and c[1] ie (0.2, 0.4) and (-1, -1).
               Here also no change. 
               Now the new elements of 'a' are (0.3, 1.0), (0.2, 0.4).
```

This process carries till 'a' is compared to the last element in the list here its upto 'd'. Then comes the turn of 'b' and same thing will continue between 'b' and 'c' then 'b and 'd' and so on.

The other rules when comparison between two actual ranges (0.1,0.3) and (0.5,1.0).

Say if two ranges totally overlap like (0.1, 0.8) and (0.3, 0.9) then,
it should take the common between them which is (0.3, 0.8).

If they don't overlap like (0.1, 0.4) and (0.5, 0.9) then,
it should choose its own which is (0.1, 0.4).

And if they partially overlap then also take the common between them.
Like (0.4, 1.0) and (0.8, 1.5) then it should choose (0.8, 1.0).

P.S. The values (0.2, 0.4) are the ranges actually indicating the actual value will vary between 0.2 to 0.4. I think now I have explained a bit more clearly. Thank you

Comment: looks like you want to compare the set of points and do something. Is this a homework?

Comment: I ... don't see a clear path from your input data to your expected output data.

Comment: yeah.. and please format your question a little bit.. some lines are slightly confusing. For e.g. `The numbers in normal brackets`, `And if range encounters range`...

Comment: The final values of 'a' is after it compared to the items of 'b', 'c' and 'd'. The same is for all the others. a's and b's 1st elements compared first and a's elements got replaced by b's as 'a' has (-1,-1) which is not in used and can be replaced when it encounters a range like I have explained in the question. Then a's value will go down to compare with c's which is empty. Then with d's and here since two ranges are being compared there is an overlap so the common between them is taken which is (0.15,0.3). Thanks

Comment: I see now effort, progress or meaning in this question.

Comment: cvani: describe your problem in mathematical terms or in terms of your problem domain. That's half the solution ;)

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: I have edited the question. I guess it makes more sense now. Thank you for suggesting that.

Comment: Did you make a mistake here? should `a[0]` and `b[0]` be `(0.3, 0.35)`? If that's the case, I've got a solution.

Comment: @agf sorry yes they should be a[0] and b[0] first. I edited my question.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Shouldn't the first item in each `a` and `b` end up as `(0.3, 0.35)` not `(0.15, 0.3)` as `b[0]` only overlaps `d[0]` from `0.3` to `0.35`?

Comment: @agf Yes you are absolutely right. Don't know what's wrong with me didn't even post the right thing. I will edit the question again. Thank you very much for pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: @agf Could you tell me your solution please? Thank you.

Comment: You still don't have it right. `a[1]` should be `(0.2, 0.4)` as it doesn't overlap with `(0.05, 0.15)`.

Comment: If this is a school project I feel bad telling you the answer. Write one function that checks a single range against another single range and gets the right answer if they overlap, don't, or one or the other is `(-1, -1)`, and saves the result to the original cell in the matrix. Write another program that generates the pairs of indices in the right order and passes them to the first function. It should only be ~20 lines of code once you get the idea.

Comment: This is a part of my research project actually. Since I'm not a programmer I can't write codes. I've got it figured out really well on paper though I made a few mistakes in the post. I would try out your suggestions but not sure how far would I go. Thanks.

Comment: @agf I'm sorry if I'm asking too much but could I not get a hint interms of code so that I could at least go ahead with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def update(mylist, row, col, cmprow, cmpcol):
    lo, hi = mylist[row][col]
    low, high = mylist[cmprow][cmpcol]

    # always replace the current value if it's (-1, -1)
    if (lo, hi) == (-1, -1):
        mylist[row][col] = low, high
        print "replacing empty", row, col, "with", cmprow, cmpcol
        return

    # never replace the current value if the ranges don't overlap
    # or the other range is (-1, -1)
    if (low, high) == (-1, -1) or lo >= high or hi <= low:
        print row, col, "doesn't overlap", cmprow, cmpcol
        return

    # set the low to the highest low and the high to the lowest high
    print "updating", row, col, "with", cmprow, cmpcol
    mylist[row][col] = max((lo, low)), min((hi, high))



def update_ranges(oldlist):
    # make a copy of the list as we're going to modify it
    mylist = oldlist[:]
    # we don't need the row titles, they just complicate things
    rowtitles, mylist = zip(*mylist)
    rows = len(mylist)
    columns = range(len(mylist[0]))

    # for each row except the last
    for i in xrange(rows - 1):
        # update it by going down all the rows below it
        for k in xrange(i+1, rows):
            # for both columns
            for j in columns:
                update(mylist, i, j, k, j)

    # put the row titles back in
    mylist = zip(rowtitles, mylist)
    return mylist



def test():
    oldlist = [ ('a', [ (-1, -1), (0.2, 0.4) ] ),
               ('b', [ (0.3, 1.0), (-1, -1) ] ),
               ('c', [ (-1, -1), (-1, -1) ] ),
               ('d', [ (0.15, 0.35), (0.05, 0.15) ] ) ]
    print "Original List"
    print '\n'.join(str(l) for l in oldlist)
    newlist = update_ranges(oldlist)
    print "New List"
    print '\n'.join(str(l) for l in newlist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Edit: Updated `update_ranges` to work for any number of columns.

Comment: Thanks a zillion. You are a star. In the question, it was just a simple example to explain the algorithm but I actually have to deal with 10 times bigger list than this but that shouldn't matter. Thank you again. I'll try this out.

Comment: So long as the format is the same, it will work for any number of rows. I'll edit in in a second to work for any number of columns.