# dealing with an empty list inside a list

Tags: python

I have a list which looks  something like this:

```
mylist = ([(0.1, 0.5),(0.4, 1.0)], [(0.2, 0.4),(0.15, 0.6)], None, [(0.35, 0.8),(0.05, 1.0)])
```

What I would like to know is how do I check for the empty entry or None in the list and if there is one then it should continue further ignoring it. Something like,

```
if mylist == something :
    do this

if mylist == [] or () or None :
    ignore and continue
```

I am not able to put that into a code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for sublist in mylist:
    if sublist is None:
        #what to do with None
        continue
    elif not sublist and isinstance(sublist, list):
        #what to do if it's an empty list
        continue
    elif not isinstance(sublist, list):
        #what to do if it's not a list
        continue
    #what to do if it's a list and not empty
```

Alternatively, you could leave out the 'continues' and put the general case in an `else` clause, only check for some of the possible circumstances, or nest the ifs.

Generally, if you knew you'd only get `None` or a container, just `if not sublist: continue` is adequate to ignore empty containers and `None`. To filter these values out of the list, do

```
mylist = [sublist for sublist in mylist if sublist]
```

Edit: You can't do this in the `update` function. You should pre-filter the list. Where you have

```
mylist = oldlist[:]
```

replace it with

```
mylist = [sublist for sublist in oldlist if sublist]
```

If the row name `a`, `b`, or whatever is there, but the rest is empty / `None`, then do

```
mylist = [sublist for sublist in oldlist if sublist[1]]
```

and this will filter on the truth value of the 2nd item intead of the first item / row title.

Comment: I followed your suggestion on the question which I had asked on Thursday which was this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949211/comparing-and-replacing-the-elements-of-a-nested-list. So in the same list there are 'none' in between which I need to ignore and proceed. Thanks

Comment: In the update() function before the comparison starts it should check if the list has 'None' if it has then ignore it and continue. I added the lines while True.... if (lo, hi) == None :....continue. But that doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: I also tried for lo, hi in mylist :
                 if (lo, hi) == None :
                    continue not sure if that is correct. But this gives an error saying "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. But I tried with the actual list which is massive, there are no errors at all. But the values are exactly the same in the input list and the output list. It doesn't even count the number of rows and columns right. I have been trying to figure that out but couldn't. Also if I use this line rowtitles, mylist = zip(*mylist) then it gives an error as ValueError: too many values to unpack. Thanks

Comment: Then the list isn't really in the form you said, `[(a,[(#, #), (#, #)]), (b,[(#, #), (#, #)])]`, as that would unpack that way fine. If you don't post __exactly__ the data structure you have, I can't help. If it's a dictionary, for example, use `rowtitles, mylist = zip(*sorted(mylist.iteritems()))` to separate the two, and recompose them like `mylist = dict(zip(rowtitles, mylist))`. I think you need to take a look at some Python tutorials or find a computer science student at your university to help.

Comment: Thank you. That's the trouble, I haven't got anyone to help me with python and I am doing it for the first time. The list is in the form as this [('a',[(#, #), (#, #)]), ('b',[(#, #), (#, #)])] so it is rather in a dict form I guess. But it is still not working, it works with a small data but not with big one. Perhaps I have made a silly mistake as it should work with any amount of data. I would check thoroughly everything. Thank you again.

Comment: That's not a `dict`; in Python, a `dict` is a specific type. That is a `list`. The `rowtitles, mylist = zip(*mylist)` does three things -- the `*` splits mylist into all of it's sublists, the `zip` takes the first item of each sublist and makes a new list (`a`, `b`, etc), and the second item of each sublist to make a new list (`[...]` in each sublist). It then assigns those two new lists to `rowtitles` and `mylist`. If there are more than two items per sublist, (a title and a list of data), you'll get that `ValueError`.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, in python

```
[], (), 0, "", None, False
```

all of these means that the value is False

Therefore:

```
newList = [i for i in myList if i] # this will create a new list which does not have any empty item

emptyList = [i for i in myList if not i] # this will create a new list which has ONLY empty items
```

or as you asked:

```
for i in myList:
    if i: 
      # do whatever you want with your assigned values
    else:
      # do whatever you want with null values (i.e. [] or () or {} or None or False...)
```

and then you can do whatever you want with your new list :)

Comment: Use `if not i` not `if i == False`.

Comment: @agf, correct sorry just thought as c#, I'm editing right away

Comment: I think `filter(bool, mylist)` is more readable than `[i for i in mylist if i]`(or generator version). I don't understand the reason of `map` or `filter` is being bad practices.

Answer (score 1):

I will just do this:

```
for x in mylist:
    if not x:
        continue

    #--> do what you want to do
```

but I have to say the first answer with comprehension list is more clean unless you need to do a complicated stuff inside the for statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about this piece of code:

```
for x in mylist:
     if x is None or x == [] or x == ():
             continue
     else:
             do this
```

Comment: hmmm that's horrible, is long and not pythonic. Why you don't like the if not x: continue?